# How to connect Google Cloud ASP.NET Framework instance to a database instance hosted on Oracle Cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, google-cloud-platform, odp.net, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have deployed an ASP.NET Framework instance on Google cloud and read from other posts that it is possible to create an Oracle database instance on Google cloud but I may have to pay a hefty sum for Oracle licenses.

Since I have a free trial Oracle database instance on Oracle Cloud, I wanted to know if it is possible to install ODP.NET driver for my instance in Google Cloud and make it connect to Oracle Cloud database.

I can connect to the database instance on Oracle cloud from my computer after installing the drivers on my computer. I just need to know if I can do the same thing for my instance in Google Cloud.

So far I can see from VPC network peering, it can link to another database instance but both instances must be on Google Cloud.

Comment: You may want to rewrite this question with a more generic title to attract  more attention from Google Cloud experts, since this  doesn't seem to have much to do with ODP.NET or Oracle Cloud. You just want to find out how to connect from Google Cloud to the internet via TCP/IP on a particular port.

Comment: @Ronny, Not sure if I don't the question. But it seems like you are trying to connect an app running in asp.net framework in a VM instance on Google Cloud Platform? If yes, I don't see why that will not work if you are already able to connect via On Prem computer. Did you try the steps provided in this tutorial on ["Connecting to a Database Cloud Service (DBaaS) Instance Through an SSH Tunnel"?](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/dbaas/obe_dbaas_connecting_to_an_instance/obe_dbaas_connecting_to_an_instance.html). Can you share any error message you're getting?